# Как откатиться до предыдущего коммита?

Tags: git, git-commit

Я удаллил все файлы кроме РИДМИ, и сделал коммит. открыл историю, тыкаю, нашшел нужный мне коммит где были все файлы, и они еще не удалены. Как мне откатиться до того коммита? Иными словами коммиты это как сейвы в играх, как мне сделать ЛОАД определенного коммита? (появится он в истории, не появится, перезапишет хед, и.т.п вообще плевать, я просто хочу файлы получить, скопировать их в другую папку и всё, как мне это сделать подскажите пожалуйста?)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выберите в меню `Reset Current Branch to Here`, затем выберите пункт `hard` и нажмите `Reset`.

Comment: А я вот так и делал первым делом, но он всё ровно показывает то чтот на скрине. Мож дело в том что "выбрана одна ветка, а ресеты происходят в другой"? или тип того?

Comment: не, `hard` ресет должен вообще всё что было отктатить назад и воссоздать состояние этого коммита. Может у вас какие-то конфликты? Попробуйте удалить Readme.md

Comment: хм, именно этот коммит так лагал, с предыдущим всё сработало, видимо баг вебшторма (вебшторм сбоку отображал будто в этом коммите много файлов, а это не так, тут УЖЕ один ридми оставался, спасибо большое за помощь)